# How to connect a published bot to bot channel registration on Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure. I had published a bot (developed locally) to Azure, e.g. named MyBot. It was shown as web service. Then I had created a bot channel registration on Azure e.g. named MyRegistration. As instructed, I wrote down the AppID and client secrete value from MyRegistration. In My Registration->settings, I put https://MyBot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages to the messaging endpoint. In MyBot->Configureation->Application settings, I added "MicrosoftAppId" and "MicrosoftAppPassword" and their values. I turned on "Web sockets" in MyBot->Configureation->General settings. I saved all the changes.

When I run "Test in Web Chat" in MyRegistration, nothing happened. In MyRegistration->Channels, there was "Issues" saying "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError".

Can anybody help to point to what the reasons of failure were? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the root reason, but I deployed my bot and go through this process but everything works perfectly for me. This is my steps below:

1. Deploy my bot service to Azure as a web app.
2. Create a Bot Channels registration, config my bot-message endpoint and Note Microsoft App ID:
   [image]
3. Create a new secret, and note its value by clicking "Manage" Link:
   [image]
4. Go to app service, and config App ID and App Password
   [image]
5. Back to bot channel and have a web test. everything works as excepted:
   [image]